# Foreach/if addition and subtraction

Tags: php

I've got a foreach loop in PHP that chucks out numbers from a GPX file and produces a table.

For example:

```
Distance | Elevation
--------------------
0        | 268
0.27     | 294
0.87     | 294
1.14     | 321
1.25     | 324
1.49     | 371
2.30     | 399
3.00     | 372
3.91     | 346
```

I want to add up when the elevation gets higher. So, for this table:

Increase: 294 - 268 = 26, 294 - 294 = 0 (26), 321 - 294 = 27 (53), 324 - 321 = 3 (56)..... and so on

I also want to count when it decreases and keep it separate to get total increase and total decrease in elevation.

So, I'm basically wanting to ask if each previous number is higher or lower and then, depending on that, add it to a variable for use later.

Any ideas?

**I tried to keep it simple but code was asked for... apologies in advance!**

```
<?php
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array())
{
    $arrData = array();

    // if input is object, convert into array
    if (is_object($arrObjData)) {
        $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);
    }

    if (is_array($arrObjData)) {
        foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
            if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call
            }
            if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
                continue;
            }
            $arrData[$index] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
}

//$xmlUrl = "../wp-content/uploads/2012/11/stoodley-pike-walk-cragg-vale-withens-clough-circular.gpx"; // XML feed file/URL
$uploadyr = $_GET['yr'];
$uploadmth = $_GET['mth'];
$gpx = $_GET['gpx'];

$xmlUrl = "../wp-content/uploads/" . $uploadyr . "/" . $uploadmth . "/" . $gpx . ".gpx";
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);
?>

<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Graph</title>

    <!--<link href="visualize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="visualize-light.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="visualize-override.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="visualize.jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#elevation').visualize({
                type: 'area',
                parseDirection: 'y',
                colors: ['#339933','#00ff00','#0000ff','#ffff00','#ff00ff','#00ffff','#000000','#666666','#AAAAAA']
            });
            $('.visualize-labels-x li:odd').hide();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<?php

echo '<table id="elevation"><caption>Elevation Profile</caption><thead><td>Total Distance (mi)</td><th>Elevation</th></thead><tbody>';

foreach($arrXml["rte"]["rtept"] as $single){

        $lat1 = $prevLat;
        $lng1 = $prevLon;
        if($prevLat == null && $prevLon == null){
            $lat1 = $single["@attributes"]["lat"];
            $lng1 = $single["@attributes"]["lon"];
        }
        $lat2 = $single["@attributes"]["lat"];
        $lng2 = $single["@attributes"]["lon"];

        $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
        $lat1 *= $pi80;
        $lng1 *= $pi80;
        $lat2 *= $pi80;
        $lng2 *= $pi80;

        $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
        $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
        $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
        $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
        $km = $r * $c;

        $distance += $km;

        $buildrow = '';
        $buildrow .= '<tr>';     
        if($prevLat !== null && $prevLon !== null){
            $buildrow .= '<th>' . number_format(($miles ? ($distance * 0.621371192) : $distance),2) . '</th>';
        } else {
            $buildrow .= '<th>0</th>';
        }
        $buildrow .= '<td>' . number_format($single["ele"],0) . '</td>';
        $buildrow .= '</tr>';

        echo $buildrow;

    $prevLat = $single["@attributes"]["lat"];
    $prevLon = $single["@attributes"]["lon"];
}
echo '</tbody></table>';

echo '<p>Total Distance: ' . number_format($distance,2) . 'mi</p>';

?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Before the loop, make a variable `$prevVal`.  Update it the *end* of each loop.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I've got one of those to add up the distances, that's no problem. It's the figuring out if the prev value is higher or lower then adding it to the correct variable that I'm struggling to get my head around. I imagine it's a fairly simple if, else loop withing my foreach but can't figure it out.

Comment: @ScottBrown: `if($val > $prevVal){} elseif($val < $prevVal){}`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for your help, I ended up doing that like this: `if($prevEle > $single["ele"]){ $eleDown += $prevEle - $single["ele"]; } elseif($prevEle < $single["ele"]){ $eleUp += $single["ele"] - $prevEle; }`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Add it as an answer and I'll accept if you like (despite the fact it will look a little churlish after all the lovely code that people have written for me!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply need to add a variable before the loop to hold the previous value.  Say `$prevValue`.  Then in the loop, at the *end* of the loop, you set it to the *current* value.  When the loop runs the next one, it'll be the *previous* value.

Then, just check if it's more or less then the *current* value.

```
if($val > $prevVal){}
elseif($val < $prevVal){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $elevationTotals = array('up' => 0,'down' =>0);
 $lastelevation = false;
 foreach($gpxdata as $key => $data){
      if($lastelevation !== false){
          $gpxdata[$key]['ElevationAlteration'] = $gpxdata['Elevation'] - $lastelevation;
          if($gpxdata[$key]['ElevationAlteration'] > 0){
               $elevationTotals['up'] += $gpxdata[$key]['ElevationAlteration'];
          } else {
               $elevationTotals['down'] += abs($gpxdata[$key]['ElevationAlteration']);
          }
      } else {
         $gpxdata[$key]['ElevationAlteration'] = 0;
      }
      $lastelevation = $gpxdata['Elevation'];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I made my way from the if statement in the comments but I'll take a look at your code as I like the way you've gone about things here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Calculates elevation information for a given array
 */
class ElevationInfo {
  private $arrHeight= array();
  private $intTotal= 0;
  private $intUpHill= 0;
  private $intDownHill= 0;

  public function __construct($arrHeight) {
    $this->arrHeight= $arrHeight;
    $this->calculate();
  }

  private function calculate() {
    $intLast=0;
    if (is_array($this->arrHeight)) {
      foreach ($this->arrHeight as $val) {
        if ($val > $intLast) {
            $this->intTotal += $val-$intLast;
            $this->intUpHill += $val-$intLast;
        } else {
            $this->intTotal += $intLast-$val;
            $this->intDownHill += $intLast-$val;
        }
        $intLast=$val;
      }
    }
  }

  public function getTotal() {
    return $this->intTotal;
  }

  public function getUpHill() {
    return $this->intUpHill;
  }

  public function getDownHill() {
    return $this->intDownHill;
  }
}

// define heights field
$arrHeight= array(268,294,294,321,324,371,399,372,346);

$elevation= new ElevationInfo($arrHeight);
print sprintf('Total: %s<br />Up hill: %s<br />Down hill: %s',
    $elevation->getTotal(), 
    $elevation->getUpHill(),
    $elevation->getDownHill());
```

This will iterate over a given array, calculate the totals and ups and downs and will let you allow getting the decrease, increase and totals using the class methods "getDownHill()", "getUpHill" and "getTotal".
Hope I didn't overlook anything, couldn't test the code yet but I think it should work.

Comment: Sorry I missed the GPX part. @RocketHazmat 's improvements should get you to the point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but I managed to get it figured out from the if loop in the comments. I'll have a look at your code though as it looks very well constructed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the upvote and hope my code may help a little!